# $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right \rfloor=\frac{n-S_n}{p-1}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers, ceiling-and-floor-functions

If $p$ is a prime number, $n$ is a natural number, and $S_n$ is the sum of the digits of $n$ when expressed in base $p$.

> Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\left \lfloor \frac{n}{p^k} \right \rfloor=\frac{n-S_n}{p-1}$.

Interestingly, any side of the equality can be used to determine the number of factors of $p$ in $n!$.

---

I have no problem with changing the base from $10$ to $p$, my problem is how to tell if the equality hold true for  any prime $p$ and any natural number $n$.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml) is a very useful link.

Answer (score 2):

Write 
$$n=\sum_{j=0}^r a_jp^j$$
where the $0\le a_j<p$ are the base $p$-digits.
Then
$$\left\lfloor\frac n{p^k}\right\rfloor=\sum_{j=k}^r a_jp^{j-k}$$
and then
$$\sum_{k=1}^r\left\lfloor\frac n{p^k}\right\rfloor
=\sum_{k=1}^r\sum_{j=k}^r a_jp^{j-k}
=\sum_{j=0}^ra_j\sum_{k=1}^jp^{j-k}=\sum_{j=0}^ra_j\frac{p^j-1}{p-1}$$
etc.

Comment: To be honest, I did not get it. Could you please explain? Thanks dear